# How do I pass props in from a separate component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get my head around props and how they work exactly. Here is my layout so far.

I have created a page called "TodoData.js" which has all of my Todos

```
    const todoss = [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: "First Todo"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            text: "Second Todo"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            text: "Third Todo"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            text: "Fourth Todo"
        }
    ]

    export default todoss;
```

I then have my main page "Todolist.js", I have imported the data with "import TodoData from './TodoData'" at the top but I can't figure out exactly how to take that data and map it out onto the page, how would i do this?

Comment: you are just importing your data from js file there is no concept of props here. If you import data as todoData just map on this variable and render your data.

Comment: Forgive me I am really new to React, sorry. So how would I display this data?

Comment: You can do as Asaf told you or you can import like this `import TodoData from 'path-of-your-file'` and add map over it like `TodoData.map(data=> data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` function to iterate an array.

```
import TodoData from './TodoData'

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {TodoData.map(function(data, idx){
                 return (<li key={idx}>{data.id}:{data.text}</li>)
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is the output:

1:First Todo
2:Second Todo
3:Third Todo
4:Fourth Todo

You can use any styling you need.

Answer (score 1):

Saving data internally as `state` is the "React" way of handling data.

In a real world application this data is going to come from an external source and if the developer doesn't know how to save data internally he will have no idea what to do.

[components-and-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

[state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

Don't import the data, save it in the `state` of your `Todos` component and pass it as `props` to `Todolist`.

```
// this will act as a presentation of our data
const TodosList = ({ todos }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(({ id, text }) => (
      <li key={id}>{text}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

// This will act as a container for our data
class Todos extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "First Todo"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Second Todo"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: "Third Todo"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        text: "Fourth Todo"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return <TodosList todos={this.state.todos} />;
  }
}
```